# I have multiple section , each cell has a button how to know indexpath.row and indexpath.section if user clicks a button

Tags: swift, uitableview, swift5

Using this code i only get tag which has indexpath.row how to make a button event from it.

TaskPlayButton is my button on that i am passing indexpath.row
for single section this would have worked by now how to do on multiple section.

Is there any other way of knowing which button is clicked?

```
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return mobileBrand.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return mobileBrand[section].modelName?.count ?? 0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TaskCell", for: indexPath) as! TaskCell

        cell.TaskName.text = mobileBrand[indexPath.section].modelName?[indexPath.row]

        cell.TaskPlayButton.tag = indexPath.row

        cell.TaskPlayButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PlayBtnClicked( _:)), for: UIButton.Event.touchUpInside)
         return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 40))
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 245, green: 245, blue: 245)

        let lbl = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 15, y: 0, width: view.frame.width - 15, height: 40))
        lbl.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
        lbl.text = mobileBrand[section].brandName
        view.addSubview(lbl)



        return view
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 40
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if selectedIndex == indexPath.row && isCollapse == true && selectedSection == indexPath.section{
            return 240

        }else{
            return 60
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        if selectedIndex == indexPath.row && selectedSection == indexPath.section{
            if self.isCollapse == false
            {
                self.isCollapse = true
            }else{
                self.isCollapse = false
            }
        }else{
            self.isCollapse = true
        }
        self.selectedIndex = indexPath.row
        self.selectedSection = indexPath.section
        TaskTableView.beginUpdates()
        TaskTableView.endUpdates()
    }

    @objc func PlayBtnClicked(_ sender : UIButton)
    {
        print(sender.tag)
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use another method like pass tag to button like this

```
cell.button.tag = (indexpath.section * 1000) + indexpath.row
```

now on your button action you can get like

```
let row = sender.tag%1000
let section = sender/1000
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use closure, please look to my codes :

```
class YourTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var button: UIButton!

    var buttonAction: ((UIButton) -> Void)?

    @objc func buttonPressed(_ sender : UIButton)) {
        self.buttonAction?(sender)
    }
}
```

Implement it to your table view delegate :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TaskCell", for: indexPath) as! TaskCell

    cell.TaskName.text = mobileBrand[indexPath.section].modelName?[indexPath.row]
    cell.TaskPlayButton.tag = indexPath.row

    cell.buttonAction = { sender in
        // do your action
        // in here, you can get indexPath.row and indexPath.section
    }

    cell.TaskPlayButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PlayBtnClicked( _:)), for: UIButton.Event.touchUpInside)
         return cell
}
```

Hope this answer can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Pass `indexPath` to cell, when click the button in this cell, you could get the current `indexPath`
2. Custom a button hold a property: indexPath. Pass `indexPath` to the button in the method `cellForRowAt`. When you click the button, you could use `button.indexPath` to get what you want.

Answer (score -1):

I just give you quick tip. It just help you on all table view in your project. 
You can follow my answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/62481414/8135121

Here it's for you.
You can grab it by position of your button.
I explain it to you.

Make a common table view extension on your class. Just use this.

```html
extension UITableView {
    
    func getCellFrom(sender : UIView,completion : @escaping (UITableViewCell,IndexPath)->()){
        var superview = sender.superview
        while let view = superview, !(view is UITableViewCell) {
            superview = view.superview
        }
        guard let cell = superview as? UITableViewCell else {
            return
        }
        guard let indexPath = self.indexPath(for: cell) else {
            return
        }
        completion(cell,indexPath)
    }
}
```

Set target from cell in your cell for row at IndexPath function.

```html
cell.TaskPlayButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PlayBtnClicked( _:)), for: UIButton.Event.touchUpInside)
```

Call this in PlayBtnClicked action method.

```html
tableView.getCellFrom(sender: sender) { [weak self] (cell, indexPath) in
      // Just use indexPath in here
      //This closure return your cell and your button's indexPath also
   }
```